# python - Repeat rows in a pandas DataFrame based on column value and add 1 day in date in each repeated row

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe like the following:

```
id, date, add_days, status
1, 2021-01-01, 3  , Completed
2, 2021-03-05, 5  , Completed
3, 2021-02-27, 3  , Pending
```

**I want to :**

1.repeat the ids and increase date by given add_days
2.make repeated rows without value in add_days column
3.make repeated rows without value in the status column

```
id, date, add_days, status
1, 2021-01-01, 3  , Completed
1, 2021-01-02,    ,
1, 2021-01-03,    ,
2, 2021-03-05, 5  , Completed
2, 2021-03-06,    ,  
2, 2021-03-07,    ,
2, 2021-03-08,    ,
2, 2021-03-09,    ,
3, 2021-02-27, 3  , Pending
3, 2021-02-28,    ,  
3, 2021-03-01,    ,
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First get the `date ranges` for each of the rows, then `explode` it, and finally get the `minimum index` for date column and assign empty string or `NaN`.

```py
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], yearfirst=True)
df['date']=df.apply(lambda row: pd.date_range(row['date'], row['date'] + \
                                pd.to_timedelta(row['add_days']-1, 'D')),
                    axis=1)
df = df.explode('date', ignore_index=True)
df.loc[~(df.index.isin(df.groupby('id')['date'].idxmin())),['add_days', 'status']] = ''
```

**OUTPUT:**

```py
    id       date add_days     status
0    1 2021-01-01        3  Completed
1    1 2021-01-02                    
2    1 2021-01-03                    
3    2 2021-03-05        5  Completed
4    2 2021-03-06                    
5    2 2021-03-07                    
6    2 2021-03-08                    
7    2 2021-03-09                    
8    3 2021-02-27        3    Pending
9    3 2021-02-28                    
10   3 2021-03-01
```

Comment: I tried this code but it give me this error :
TypeError: unhashable type: 'DatetimeIndex'

Comment: Which Python version and pandas version are you using? It seems that all three answers are not working for you, so there must be some issue in your end. I tested the code again, and its working fine.

Comment: yes, u r right after update pandas version ur solution work, thank u very much

Comment: But i'm still have a probelm where add_days equal 0 give me this error: 
ValueError: attempt to get argmin of an empty sequence
where add_days is NaN give me this error : 
ValueError: Neither `start` nor `end` can be NaT

Answer (score 0):

You can make a loop that pulls out the number from `add_days` and the day of that row, and then makes a new df with that one column, and appends and sorts.

```py
df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['date']) # our new placeholder df
l = [] # blank list that we will make our new column in
for i in range(0,len(df.index)):
    a, b = df.iloc[i]['date'], df.iloc[i]['add_days']
    for n in range(0,b-1):
        l.append(a)
        l2 = pd.Series(l)
        df3 = df2.append(pd.DataFrame(l2,columns=['date']))
df.append(df3).sort_values('date').fillna('')

    date    add_days    status
1   2021-01-01  3.0 Completed
0   2021-01-01      
1   2021-01-01      
3   2021-02-27  3.0 Pending
6   2021-02-27      
7   2021-02-27      
2   2021-03-05  5.0 Completed
2   2021-03-05      
3   2021-03-05      
4   2021-03-05      
5   2021-03-05
```

Comment: I tried this code but it give me this error : 
IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds